# Inconsistent behavior of the value of the assignment operator in C

Tags: c, gcc

In gcc, I see that

```
int a=(b=0);
```

assigns a with 0 as well. Also I learnt that an assignment is an expression with the value and assignment associated from right to left.

Now one would expect the assignment, a=0 would evaluate to false when used as part of a condition. But it is not the case. `if(a=0)` would always evaluates to true. Could someone explain the reason behind this or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: How exactly did you test that `if(a=0)`?

Comment: What make you believe that `if(a=0)` is a successful test? It is not (and it is a *statement* not an expression, so cannot be *evaluated*, only *executed*). And please read a good C programming book, and have a look inside [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) normative specification, i.e. its [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) final draft

Comment: `if(a == 0)` != `if(a = 0)`

Comment: Please compile using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to enable all warnings and debug info. Improve your code till you get no warnings at all.

Answer (score 3):

> Now one would expect the assignment, a=0 would evaluate to false when used as part of a condition.

It does.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a = 456;
  if (a=0)
    puts("(a=0) evaluates to true");
  else
    puts("(a=0) evaluates to false");
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./a.out
(a=0) evaluates to false
```

Whatever you were using to test your assumption must have been incorrect.